# Customizing video player on mobile browser

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, web, html5-video

I want to offer the user some custom actions on a video while it's playing, e.g. show a banner ad, ask a poll question, etc.

How can I achieve that on iOS Safari and/or Android Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: I Googled around (inc StackOverflow) and couldn't find anything

Comment: Actually what kind of "custom actions" you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML video player can be fully customized in desktop + mobile.

See Ghinda's excellent demo at https://dev.opera.com/articles/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/video.html